# Javascript changing multiple object values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace / change the values in an object, but I can't seem to work out how it's done or if it can even be done.

I'm trying to add `https://SiteName.com` to the start of each of the values so it will be like `https://SiteName.com\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg`

```js
var assets = [{
  "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg",
  "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg"
}, {
  "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-stone.svg",
  "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-stone.svg"
}]

Object.keys(assets).forEach(key => {
  const val = assets[key];
  console.log(val)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var assets = [{
  "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg",
  "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg"
}, {
  "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-stone.svg",
  "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-stone.svg"
}]

let url = "https://SiteName.com";

Object.keys(assets).forEach(key => {
  const val = assets[key];
  val.name = url + val.name;
  val.url = url + val.url;
});

console.log(assets)
```

Comment: What's the point of using the Object.keys method on an array? Just use forEach.

Answer (score 2):

You need a nested loop (or `forEach`) here - one to go over the elements of the `assets` array, and then, for each object in there, go over all its properties:

```js
var assets = [{
  "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg",
  "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-grass.svg"
}, {
  "name": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-stone.svg",
  "url": "\/asset\/image\/map\/map-stone.svg"
}]

assets.forEach(o => {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
      o[key] = 'https://SiteName.com' + o[key];
    })
});

console.log(assets);
```